# Bit operation used in a for loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop, bit-manipulation

I found this loop in the source code of an algorithm. I think that details about the problems aren't relevant here, because this is a really small part of the solution.

```
    void update(int i, int value, int array[], int n) {
        for(; i < n; i += ~i & (i + 1)) {
            array[i] += value;
        }
}
```

I don't really understand what happens in that for loop, is it some sort of trick? I found something similar named Fenwick trees, but they look a bit different than what I have here.

Any ideas what this loop means?

Also, found this :

"Bit Hack #9. Isolate the rightmost 0-bit.

y = ~x & (x+1)
"

Comment: I'd suggest you step thru this with pencil and paper, keeping track of `i` in either hex or binary. `~i & (i + 1)` will be the lowest power of two that evenly divides `i`. After `i += ~i & (i + 1)`, `i` will then be divisible by the next power of two (since the lowest bit got added, which will set the lowest nonzero bit to 0 and carry the 1 into the next higher position).

Comment: I can't even guess at what the point of doing that would be, but I can tell how the bits would move around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct:  the bit-hack `~i & (i + 1)` should evaluate to an integer which is all binary `0`'s, except the one corresponding to the rightmost zero-bit of `i`, which is set to binary `1`.

So at the end of each pass of the `for` loop, it adds this value to itself.  Since the corresponding bit in `i` is zero, this has the effect of setting it, without affecting any other bits in `i`.  This will strictly increase the value of `i` at each pass, until `i` overflows (or becomes `-1`, if you started with `i<0`).  In context, you can probably expect that it is called with `i>=0`, and that `i < n` is set terminate the loop before your index walks off the `array`.

The overall function should have the effect of iterating through the zero-bits of the original value of `i` from least- to most-significant, setting them one by one, and incrementing the corresponding elements of the `array`.

Fenwick trees are a clever way to accumulate and query statistics efficiently; as you say, their update loop looks a bit like this, and typically uses a comparable bit-hack.  There are bound to be multiple ways to accomplish this kind of bit-fiddling, so it is certainly possible that your source code is updating a Fenwick tree, or something comparable.

Comment: "So at the end of each pass of the for loop, it adds this value to itself. Since the corresponding bit in i is **zero**, this has the effect of setting it, without affecting any other bits in i. " Well, this is wrong and it makes the answer particularly confusing.

Comment: Please explain: where do you think it is wrong?  The rightmost zero-bit in a `i` is zero.  When adding a `1` in that bit-position, there will be no carry.  So the result, in this case, is the same as or-ing with a `1` in that bit-position: it is set, without affecting any other bits.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that from the right to the left, you have some number of 1 bits, a 0 bit, and then more bits in x.

If you add x + 1, then all the 1's at the right are changed to 0, the 0 is changed to 1, the rest is unchanged. For example xxxx011 + 1 = xxxx100.

In ~x, you have the same number of 0 bits, a 1 bit, and the inverses of the other bits. The bitwise and produces the 0 bits, one 1 bit, and since the remaining bits are and'ed with their negation, those bits are 0.

So the result of ~x & (x + 1) is a number with one 1 bit where x had its rightmost zero bit.

If you add this to x, you change the rightmost 0 to a 1. So if you do this repeatedly, you change the 0 bits in x to 1, from the right to the left.

Answer (score 1):

The `update` function iterates and sets the 0-bits of `i` from the leftmost  zero to the rightmost zero and add `value` to the `i`th element of `array`.

The `for` loop checks if `i` is less than `n`, if so, `~i & (i + 1)` would be an integer has all binary 0's, except for the rightmost bit ( i.e. 1). Then `array[i] += value` adds `value` to iterated itself.

Setting `i` to `8` and going through iterations may clear things to you.